# Unexpected failure of the task "GenerateResource"

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a mesterious error when I try to debug my universal app project this is the error that I get:

```
Unexpected failure of the task "GenerateResource"

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   à Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.TryGetPortableLibraryInfo(String libraryPath)
   à Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List`1& inputsToProcess, List`1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles)
   à Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   à Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.OutOfProcTaskAppDomainWrapperBase.InstantiateAndExecuteTask(IBuildEngine oopTaskHostNode, LoadedType taskType, String taskName, String taskLocation, String taskFile, Int32 taskLine, Int32 taskColumn, AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup, IDictionary`2 taskParams)   MyProject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

1. Open the Build menu
2. Click on Clear Solution
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Open the solution again
5. Open the Build menu
6. Click on rebuild

If this doesn't work, restart your computer and it will likely be solved